# How would I go about adding a horizontal scrollbar to this particular div element?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

What I want to do is have a way to horizontally scroll through the icons on the top bar. No matter how I try to implement `overflow` I cannot get it to work. Here is a link to the page. Link no longer exists.

Note: that the scrollbar shall not cover the background image at all. It should be immediately below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the width of that header div to be wider (width:2000px;). If you want a dynamic width (you dont know how many boxes will be in there) then you'll have to calculate the width with javascript (or serverside code like PHP).

Giving the .browser div a width of 2000px does the trick... then adjust the height of your divs to be tall enough to show the whole icon and name.

Let me know if that makes sense...

Comment: Did you try to make the .browser div have a width of 2000px?

Comment: However, that covers the background image.

Comment: You'll have to add extra height to the div (about 12px) to accomodate the height of the scroll bar (they're always inside the container).

Comment: Hmm. And if the user resizes the width of the scrollbars (particularly in Windows)?

Comment: You would have to resolve that with javascript checking the page width vs. the icon area width. You could also remake the background image to be white at the bottom for the height of the scrollbar... so when it's not there it looks blank.

Comment: Sigh. I was trying to avoid JS. Lol. I guess you're right. There's not getting around it now. :( Thanks.